# Python: how to get present date of a particular timezone more efficiently

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I solve this task by this following code. But is there any other way that is more efficient? More specifically I want to do this same job without using the `datetime.datetime.now()` method. I need the only date, not the whole datetime.

```
import pytz, datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')).date())
```

Comment: A `date` have no `timezone`, therfore you have to go with `datetime`.

Comment: `date` obviously has a `timezone`. As an example- now in Bangladesh the date is 19-11-2018, but in USA the date is 20-11-2018.

Actuality I had built a django app and host it in an US server. I want to work with my local date but the app is working with the US date.

Comment: Read [UTC_offsets_worldwide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#UTC_offsets_worldwide) and compare [Time Difference
Bangladesh Los Angeles](https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/difference/country/bd/city/5368361)

Comment: A date by itself does *not* have a time zone.  It's only when you apply a time that time zones come into play.  If you ask what date it is "now", then that is applying the current time and a time zone - either a specific or implied.  Consider if I just had a printed paper calendar, like those they sell to hang on your wall every year showing the days of the month of a particular year.  There are no time zones involved in making that calendar.  It's only when one looks at it and points to a particular square and calls it "today" that that person's local time zone comes into play.